# Vue component doesn't update when state in store is updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to do a simple todo list in Vue but I want to abstract everything out and use a dummy REST API so I can start to get used to production-level projects in Vue and it's all making my head spin. GET, PUT, and POST requests seem to be working, but I can't figure out why the list of todos doesn't update automatically when I do a successful POST request to the back end.

I've got a `TodoList` component that loops through a `todosFiltered()` computed property to show the todos. The computed property refers back to the getter `todosFiltered` in the Vuex store. I also use the `created()` lifecycle hook here to dispatch an action in the store that makes the initial GET request and then populates an array called `todos` in the store when the page is first loaded. The getter `todosFiltered` in the store returns `state.todos`, so I assumed that when my component re-renders, it would have the new `todos` array from the state grabbed from `todosFiltered`, only that's not happening. What am I missing here? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

#### TodoList.vue

(I know I'll have to work out a solution for the ids, it's on my list :p)

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <input v-model="newTodo" type="text" placeholder="What must be done?" class="todo-input" @keyup.enter="addTodo">
        <transition-group name="fade" enter-active-class="animated zoomIn" leave-active-class="animated zoomOut">
            <todo-item v-for="todo in todosFiltered" :key="todo.id" :checkAll="!anyRemaining" :todo="todo"></todo-item>
        </transition-group>
        <div class="extra-container">
            <todos-filtered></todos-filtered>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import TodosFiltered from './TodosFiltered'
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'

export default {
  name: 'todolist',
  components: {
    TodosFiltered,
    TodoItem
  },
  data() {
    return {
        beforeEditCache: '',
        newTodo: '',
        idForTodo: 10,
    }
  },
  // Methods
  methods: {
    addTodo() {
        if (this.newTodo.trim().length == 0) {
            return
        }
        this.$store.dispatch('addTodo', {
            id: this.idForTodo,
            title: this.newTodo,
            completed: false
        })
        this.newTodo = ''
        this.idForTodo++
    }
  },
  computed: {
    todosFiltered() {
        return this.$store.getters.todosFiltered
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('loadTodos')
  },
}
</script>
```

#### store.js

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        filter: 'all',
        todos: []
    },
    getters: {
        todosFiltered(state) {
            if (state.filter == 'all') {
                return state.todos
            } else if (state.filter == 'active') {
                return state.todos.filter(todo => !todo.completed)
            } else if (state.filter == 'completed') {
                return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed)
            }
            return state.todos
        },
        showClearCompleted(state) {
            return state.todos.filter(todo => todo.completed).length > 0
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        addTodo(state, todo) {
            state.todos.push(todo)
        },
        setTodos(state, todos) {
            state.todos = todos
        },
    },
    actions: {
        loadTodos(context) {
            axios.get('http://localhost:3000/todos')
            .then(r => r.data)
            .then(todos => {
                context.commit('setTodos', todos)
            })
        },
        updateTodo(context, todo) {
            axios.put('http://localhost:3000/todos/' + todo.id, {
                "id": todo.id,
                "title": todo.title,
                "completed": todo.completed
            })
        },
        addTodo(context, todo) {
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/todos', {
                "id": todo.id,
                "title": todo.title,
                "completed": todo.completed
            })
            .then(todo => {
                context.commit('addTodo', todo)
            })
        },
    }
})
```

EDIT: Here's what's going on in Vue Dev Tools when I add a todo -- `todos` in the store's state gets updated immediately, and the `todosFiltered` computed property in the `TodoList` component ALSO reflects that -- but the new todo doesn't appear in the list! Strange.

Comment: Using computed property here will not work. Because the computed property doesn't depend on any property in Vue instance. Read more here: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods

Comment: Like @DuongDang said, it wont work with a computed property because of caching

Answer (score 0):

A way to solve this can be to create what I like to call a `refresh()` method.

Basically, you will have a local list of `todos` in your `data()` method, the `refresh()` method will load all the `todos` from the store into the local `todos` list, every time you do an action, such as creating, deleting, or updating, you would call the refresh method to re-load the list for you.

So, in your `TodoList.vue`:

```js
<template>
    <todo-item v-for="todo in todosFiltered" :key="todo.id"></todo-item>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            // Where we store the local list of Todos 
            // so the component will react when we do something to it
            todosFiltered: []
        }
    },
    methods {
        refresh() {
            // Get the todo list from the store.
            // which in turn will trigger a change event so the component
            // react to what we did.
            this.todosFiltered = this.$store.getters.todosFiltered;
        },
        addTodo() {
            this.$store.dispatch('addTodo').then(() => {
                // Refresh the list after adding a new Todo
                this.refresh();
            })
        },
        updateTodo() {
            this.$store.dispatch('updateTodo').then(() => {
                // Refresh the list after updating a Todo
                this.refresh();
            })
        },
        deleteTodo() {
            this.$store.dispatch('deleteTodo').then(() => {
                // Refresh the list after deleting a Todo
                this.refresh();
            })
        }
    },
    created() {
        this.$store.dispatch('loadTodos').then( () => {
            // Refresh the list when first loaded after the Todos been saved in Vuex
            this.refresh();
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

> Don't actually delete what you already have and replace it with
>   this, just apply what's here to your code.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is using a $store.getter on the v-for loop.
Try the following:

1. Set your computed to

   todos() {
        return this.$store.todos;
   }
2. Change your v-for loop to use todo in todos
3. Add a v-if condition to the loop like v-if="filtered(todo)"
4. Create a new method called filtered (or whatever you prefer), and add your "filteredTodos" logic there, returning true/false as needed
5. If you need to share this code, you can always use a mixin and share it between your components

Hope this works for you

Comment: This didn't work :( Two posters above are saying computed properties won't work, so I need to figure out something else.